# Function's parameters with different types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an onChange function and I pass it as a props in another React Component.

I declare the Component's Props as follow:

```
  onChange: (newValue: ContentManagementCategoryType[] | OrganizationType[]) => void;
```

The onChange I am trying to pass in the component has the following format:

```
  const updateFilterCategories = (newValue: ContentManagementCategoryType[]) => {
    setFilteredCategories(newValue);
  };
```

So I got the following error:

> Type '(newValue: ContentManagementCategoryType[]) => void' is not
> assignable to type '(newValue: ContentManagementCategoryType[] |
> OrganizationType[]) => void'.   Types of parameters 'newValue' and
> 'newValue' are incompatible.

I cant figure out why I got an error since the component is wating for an onChange with **newValue** as **ContentManagementCategoryType[]** or **OrganizationType[]** and I am passing an onChange with  **ContentManagementType[]**.

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
type ValueType = (ContentManagementCategoryType | OrganizationType)[]
```

```js
onChange: (newValue: ValueType) => void;
```

```js
const updateFilterCategories = (newValue: ValueType) => {
    setFilteredCategories(newValue);
  };
```